# Run JS function on every single class

Tags: javascript, html, function

I've created a chart where the bar values are added through HTML and modified as needed in JS. The values that the JS is outputting are from the first bar, but it's not taking the values from the other bars.

Does anyone know how can I make that function to output the values for every single bar?

```js
$('.vertical .progress-fill span').each(function(){
  var to = $(".vertical .progress-fill span.to").html();
  var from = $(".vertical .progress-fill span.from").html();
  
  var percentFrom = from + "%";
  
  var pBottom = 0 + ( from.slice(0, from.length - 1) );
  var pTop = 100 - (to) + "%" ;
  
  var bottom = (pBottom) + "%";
  var top = (to - from) + "%";
  
  $(this).parent().css({
    'height' : top,
    'top' : pTop,
    'bottom' : percentFrom,
  });
});


/*$('.vertical .progress-fill span').each(function(){
  var percent = $(this).html();
  var pTop = 100 - ( percent.slice(0, percent.length - 1) ) + "%";
  $(this).parent().css({
    'height' : percent,
    'top' : pTop
  });
});*/
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body {
  background: #999;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

/* Vertical */

.vertical .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.vertical .progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.vertical .progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  background: #825;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container vertical flat">

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">90</span>
        <span class="from">20</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">75</span>
        <span class="from">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">60</span>
        <span class="from">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">100</span>
        <span class="from">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">50</span>
        <span class="from">40</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">70</span>
        <span class="from">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the code here

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVeLbx)

Comment: When the SO Tool tells you that you cannot post a link to codepen without code, do **not** simple code indent text, that's **not** what SO wanted you to do! - CodePen links can change, go offline or die, hence you should add your code to the question in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead or as well as.

Comment: All right @Nope. Thank you for letting me know. Just joined the forum and still learning

Comment: When you asked the question there was a **massive** big box to the right saying `How to Ask` which has links to several FAQs, including [**How to ask a question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - It's the first thing you see so you can learn, if you don't read them but instead right away go to "cheating" your way into being able to post the question, you don't learn :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping on wrong element.

loop through `.progress-fill`

```
$('.vertical .progress-fill').each(function(){
  var to = $(this).find(".to").html();
  var from = $(this).find(".from").html();

  var percentFrom = from + "%";

  var pBottom = 0 + ( from.slice(0, from.length - 1) );
  var pTop = 100 - (to) + "%" ;

  var bottom = (pBottom) + "%";
  var top = (to - from) + "%";

  $(this).parent().css({
    'height' : top,
    'top' : pTop,
    'bottom' : percentFrom,
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJYqNg

Answer (score 0):

A couple of mistakes there

- You were not getting `to` and `from` each `progress-fill` .

like

```
  var to = $(this).find(".to").html();
  var from = $(this).find(".from").html();
```

- Change selector `$('.vertical .progress-fill span')` to `$('.vertical .progress-fill')`

like

```
$('.vertical .progress-fill').each(function(){
```

Comment: I just added it, but that way is not taking the values from TO and FROM: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQOPWL

Comment: He is looping on `span`. how will he find `.to` and `.from` elements inside `span`

Comment: @Kenny Nope, span shouldn't be looped. Check the pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRPmYg

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thank you for your help, both answers worked in the end

Comment: @gurvinder372 you edited your answer. Earlier you didn't mentioned your changes in selector for each.... After editing i see it. Removed downvote

Comment: @Kenny yeah, I missed out on editing the answer, it was done in attached pen though. Your answer deserved to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are iterating over all your spans:

```
<span class="to">90</span>
<span class="from">20</span>
<span class="to">75</span>
<span class="from">10</span>
<span class="to">60</span>
<span class="from">10</span>
<span class="to">100</span>
<span class="to">50</span>
<span class="from">40</span>
<span class="from">0</span>
<span class="to">70</span>
<span class="from">30</span>
```

You have to iterate over `.progress-fill` instead:

```
$('.vertical .progress-fill').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var to = $this.find("span.to").html();
  var from = $this.find("span.from").html();

  var percentFrom = from + "%";

  var pBottom = 0 + ( from.slice(0, from.length - 1) );
  var pTop = 100 - (to) + "%" ;

  var bottom = (pBottom) + "%";
  var top = (to - from) + "%";

  $(this).parent().css({
    'height' : top,
    'top' : pTop,
    'bottom' : percentFrom,
  });
});
```

```js
$('.vertical .progress-fill').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var to = $this.find("span.to").html();
  var from = $this.find("span.from").html();
 
  var percentFrom = from + "%";
  
  var pBottom = 0 + ( from.slice(0, from.length - 1) );
  var pTop = 100 - (to) + "%" ;
  
  var bottom = (pBottom) + "%";
  var top = (to - from) + "%";
  
  $(this).parent().css({
    'height' : top,
    'top' : pTop,
    'bottom' : percentFrom,
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body {
  background: #999;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #333;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

/* Vertical */

.vertical .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.vertical .progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.vertical .progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  background: #825;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container vertical flat">

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">90</span>
        <span class="from">20</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">75</span>
        <span class="from">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">60</span>
        <span class="from">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">100</span>
        <span class="from">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">50</span>
        <span class="from">40</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="to">70</span>
        <span class="from">30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```